# Cannot add view to LinearLayout in OnCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-widget, oncreate

I'm creating a launcher app and I wanted that when the user launch the app the widget that he previously add are load. The problem is that when I'm trying to load the Widget in the onCreate function it crash saying that it cannot find my view.

Here is my mainActivity.kt:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        AppDatabase.init(this, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME) // Just DB stuff using room 

        widgetSelector = WidgetSelector(this)

        // Fragment initialisation 
        homeScreen = HomeFragment()
        appListScreen = AppListFragment(this, widgetSelector)
        fragmentMgr = supportFragmentManager
        pagerAdapter =
            HomeAdapter(fragmentMgr)
        pagerAdapter.addFragments(homeScreen)
        pagerAdapter.addFragments(appListScreen)
        homeViewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        // End of fragment initialisation 

        widgetSelector.loadWidget() // /!\ This is the problematic line 
    }
```

Here is the loadWidget function. Every Widget are already store in the database I'm just getting them and trying to display them:

```
fun createWidget(id: Int) {
        val appWidgetInfo: AppWidgetProviderInfo = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(id)
        val hostView: AppWidgetHostView =
            appWidgetHost.createView(mainActivity, id, appWidgetInfo)
        hostView.setAppWidget(id, appWidgetInfo)
        mainActivity.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.list_widget).addView(hostView) // /!\ This line is the problem again
}

fun loadWidget() {
        AppDatabase.INSTANCE?.itemDAO()?.getAll()?.forEach {
            createWidget(it.appWidgetId)
        }
}
```

And here is the basic fragment where I try to add the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorLMTBlueBlack">

</LinearLayout>
```

When I launch my app I got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.letmethink.lmtapp, PID: 28499
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.letmethink.lmtapp/com.letmethink.lmtapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.letmethink.lmtapp.widget.WidgetSelector.createWidget(WidgetSelector.kt:59)
        at com.letmethink.lmtapp.widget.WidgetSelector.loadWidget(WidgetSelector.kt:71)
        at com.letmethink.lmtapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:49)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
```

I already try many things as moving the addView to mainActivity or try to execute the loadWidget function onPostCreated(). I'm pretty sure that the problem come from the fact that I'm using fragment that why I tried to call the function in the onCreateView of the fragment but it didn't work. I call this function later in the code (for exemple in onResult) and it works perfectly.

```
override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        widgetSelector.reloadWidget()
        val widgetSelector = WidgetSelector(this)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val id = data!!.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET) {
                widgetSelector.configureWidget(id)
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET) {
                widgetSelector.createWidget(id)
            }
            AppDatabase.INSTANCE?.itemDAO()?.insert(Widget(id))
            widgetSelector.reloadWidget()
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
            val appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1)
            if (appWidgetId != -1) {
                widgetSelector.appWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `findViewById` on `mainActivity` but you said that `list_widget` is in Fragment?

Comment: The fragment is in the mainActivity

Comment: Don't do `mainActivity.findViewById`, instead in`onViewCreated` of ur fragmnet do `view.findViewById`

Comment: I've already try that but I didn't work

Comment: Yeah but `LinearLayout` is in fragment and you are trying to get the reference from `mainActivity` in this line 
`mainActivity.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.list_widget).addView(hostView)`

It should be like this 
`fragmentView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.list_widget).addView(hostView)`

Comment: The problem is not here I have already try to do so and as you can see the code works in the onActivityResult